# Why a "RedisTemplate" can convert to a "ListOperations"

Tags: java, spring

I'm reading the spring-data-redis reference guide.
In the 5.5 capther,we create the `redisTemplate` bean in spring config xml File.

```
<bean id="redisTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
    p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>
```

And then inject it as ListOperations as following code:

```
public class Example {
  @Autowired
  private RedisTemplate<String, String> template;

  @Resource(name="redisTemplate")
  private ListOperations<String, String> listOps;

  public void addLink(String userId, URL url) {
    listOps.leftPush(userId, url.toExternalForm());
  }
}
```

I know the annotation `@Resource` can inject bean from spring container by name,But `RedisTemplate` and `ListOperations` are different interface Type.Then I look over the `ListOperations`'s implementation source code `DefaultListOperations`.

```
class DefaultListOperations<K, V> extends AbstractOperations<K, V> implements ListOperations<K, V> {
    DefaultListOperations(RedisTemplate<K, V> template) {
        super(template);
    }
}
```

I guess maybe `@Resource` can also inject necessary property to the bean constructor.So I test the following code to verify my guess:

```
@Component("basicBean")
public class BasicBean {
}
@Component
public class ComplicateBean {
    @Autowired
    public ComplicateBean(BasicBean basicBean) {
    }
}
@Component
public class DemoBean {
    @Resource(name="basicBean")
    private ComplicateBean complicateBean;
}
```

but I got an `BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException`

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException:
Bean named 'basicBean' is expected to be of type 'com.fan.beans.ComplicateBean' 
but was actually of type 'com.fan.beans.BasicBean'
```

So my question is:Why a `RedisTemplate` bean can inject as `ListOperations`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring IOC container do the magic for you:

```
class ListOperationsEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    ListOperationsEditor() {
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        if(value instanceof RedisOperations) {
            super.setValue(((RedisOperations)value).opsForList());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Editor supports only conversion of type " + RedisOperations.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Framework uses the implementation class of `java.beans.PropertyEditor` interface to convert types.

Spring Data Redis provides `ListOperationsEditor` to convert `RedisTemplate` to `ListOperations` ( https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/2.2.5.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ListOperationsEditor.java
 ) :

```java
class ListOperationsEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof RedisOperations) {
            super.setValue(((RedisOperations) value).opsForList());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Editor supports only conversion of type " + RedisOperations.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `RedisTemplate` is the implementation class of `RedisOperations`.

> Note also that the standard JavaBeans infrastructure automatically discovers PropertyEditor classes (without you having to register them explicitly) if they are in the same package as the class they handle and have the same name as that class, with Editor appended. For example, one could have the following class and package structure, which would be sufficient for the SomethingEditor class to be recognized and used as the PropertyEditor for Something-typed properties.

Copy from : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-beans-conversion

Both the `ListOperations` class and the `ListOperationsEditor` are under the `org.springframework.data.redis.core` package, so it can be automatically discovered and take effect.

Comment: Great answer, too bad it went underappreciated.