# How is RedisTemplate injected into XXOperations(HashOperations ect.) using spring data (redis)

Tags: spring, inject, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am using Spring Data Redis but the official docs confused me:

```
    <!-- redis template definition -->
    <bean id="redisTemplate" 
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
        p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>
```

the `redisTemplate` was injected into `ListOperations`:

```
// inject the template as ListOperations
  @Resource(name="redisTemplate")
  private ListOperations<String, String> listOps;
```

but the RedisTemplate didn't extend the ListOperations：

```
- public class RedisTemplate<K, V> extends RedisAccessor implements RedisOperations<K, V>, BeanClassLoaderAware
- public class RedisAccessor implements InitializingBean
```

I am wondering how is redisTemplate injected into XXXOperations.

my spring-data-redis version is 1.8.1.RELEASE
jedis version is 2.9.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why a "RedisTemplate" can convert to a "ListOperations"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006197/why-a-redistemplate-can-convert-to-a-listoperations)

Answer (score 0):

look at this class `ListOperationsEditor`

```
class ListOperationsEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

public void setValue(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof RedisOperations) {
        super.setValue(((RedisOperations) value).opsForList());
    } else {
        throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("Editor supports only conversion of type " + RedisOperations.class);
    }
}
```

}

**Use PropertyEditorSupport to transform type   (RedisTemplate -> ListOperations)**