# Puzzled with @Resource injection with name attribute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I'm puzzled with such kind of dependency injection shown as an example in spring data redis:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer

```
  // inject the template as ListOperations
  @Resource(name="redisTemplate")
  private ListOperations<String, String> listOps;
```

Taking into consideration that redisTemplate is a bean of type RedisTemplate, how does spring manage to retrieve the listOps from the redisTemplate bean ?

This is working and I'm mainly interested to find a piece of documentation explaining this behaviour or the piece of code handling that.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Take a look into [this post](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire)

Comment: It doesn't. `RedisTemplate` implements the `ListOperations` interface.

Comment: RedisTemplate does not implement ListOperations.

Just found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006197/why-a-redistemplate-can-convert-to-a-listoperations

Comment: I just found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006197/why-a-redistemplate-can-convert-to-a-listoperations

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is working thanks to ListOperationsEditor class.

```
class ListOperationsEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    ListOperationsEditor() {
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        if(value instanceof RedisOperations) {
            super.setValue(((RedisOperations)value).opsForList());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Editor supports only conversion of type " + RedisOperations.class);
        }
    }
}
```